# How to solve CollectionView contentOffSet problem with Horizontal scroll and vertical scroll?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have this a storyboard structure:

CollectionView (Vertical Scroll)> CollectionViewCell> Label + CollectionView (Horizontal Scroll) > CollectionViewCell

That is, I have the first CollectionView (Vertical Scroll) that does vertical scroll occupying the entire screen, inside I have CollectionViewCell that has a label for the category ("Batata") and second CollectionView (Horizontal Scroll), where inside it exists collectionViewCell that shows "Batatinha" .

Ps: for all collectionViewCell uses Xibs

My problem is ... when I scroll horizontally on a line, then I scroll vertical there are other lines that will get the same offset from the line where I had already done horizontal scrolling.
  I've tried in many different and possible ways but never got it, my thinking is not getting there.
  Has anyone ever been the same problem? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the offset to your datasource perhaps storing the offset in a dictionary so that the offset is only assigned to cells with the proper IndexPath 
i.e. `offSets:[IndexPath:CGPoint]`

As an alternative, If you don't want to store the previous offset, you can reset the offset to `collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero` inside of the ColectionViewCell's `init()` for the cell containing the horriztonal CollectionView.

Hope his helps

Best Of Luck!